# When i try to run app in debug mode the following error occurs. flutter

Tags: flutter

This error comes while I try to make body of scaffold scrollable and I have add flutter_html package in my pubspecs.yaml at that time.

I think the problem is from the new inserted package but not confirmed. Can you please help me in solving this problem?

> Error: The argument type 'void Function(DragStartDetails, DragUpdateDetails)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(TapDragUpdateDetails)?'.
>
> gesture_detector_builder.dart:197
>
> - 'DragStartDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/gestures/drag_details.dart'
>   ('../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/drag_details.dart').
>   drag_details.dart:1
> - 'DragUpdateDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/gestures/drag_details.dart'
>   ('../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/drag_details.dart').
>   drag_details.dart:1
> - 'TapDragUpdateDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/tap_and_drag_gestures.dart' ('../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/tap_and_drag_gestures.dart').
>
> tap_and_drag_gestures.dart:1
> onDragSelectionUpdate: onDragSelectionUpdate,
> ^
>
> Error: The argument type 'void Function(DragEndDetails)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(TapDragEndDetails)?'.
>
> gesture_detector_builder.dart:198
>
> - 'DragEndDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/gestures/drag_details.dart' ('../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/gestures/drag_details.dart').
>   drag_details.dart:1
> - 'TapDragEndDetails' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/tap_and_drag_gestures.dart' ('../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/tap_and_drag_gestures.dart').
>   tap_and_drag_gestures.dart:1
>   onDragSelectionEnd: onDragSelectionEnd,
>   ^
>   Failed to compile application

This is the error I am getting in debug console when trying to run app
Can you know why this error occurs? Because it appears unexpectedly and I don't know why it happens.

This is my code in which I lastly editing:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:newstv/controlller/news_controller.dart';
import 'package:newstv/screens/card_widget.dart';
import '../colors.dart';

class NewsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
   const NewsScreen({super.key});

   @override
        State<NewsScreen> createState() => _NewsScreenState();
     }

        class _NewsScreenState extends State<NewsScreen> {
      NewsController newsController = Get.put(NewsController());
    var refreshKey = GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>();
 
        @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
           return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: ThemeCode.background,
          elevation: 0,
          title:
              // column column starts here
              Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment:
                CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text(
                'Voice of Neemuch',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 19,
                  color: ThemeCode.redcolor,
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                'We with you',
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: ThemeCode.black,
                    fontSize: 15),
              )
            ],
          ),
          // column ends here

          actions: [
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.search,
                color: ThemeCode.black,
                size: 35,
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              width: 20,
            )
          ],
        ),
        body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Wrap(
              alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: 7,
                      right: 7,
                      top: 4,
                      bottom: 4),
                  child: ColoredBox(
                    color: Colors.amberAccent,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding:
                          const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Wrap(
                        alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          const Text(
                              'Contact for news and Advertisement'),
                          const SizedBox(
                            width: 4,
                          ),
                          const Icon(
                              Icons.phonelink_sharp),
                          const SizedBox(
                            width: 4,
                          ),
                          TextButton(
                              onPressed: () {},
                              child: const Text(
                                  '91 4543******'))
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                //List view builder ode goes here

                Obx(() {
                  if (newsController
                      .isDataLoading.value) {
                    return const Center(
                      child:
                          CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    );
                  } else if (newsController.newsModel!
                      .responseData.isEmpty) {
                    return const Center(
                      child: Text('Data not available'),
                    );
                  }
                  return RefreshIndicator(
                    key: refreshKey,
                    onRefresh: () =>
                        newsController.getApi(),
                    child: ListView.builder(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                        physics:
                            const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: newsController
                            .newsModel
                            ?.responseData
                            .length,
                        itemBuilder:
                            (BuildContext context,
                                int index) {
                          return CardWidget(
                              model: newsController
                                  .newsModel!
                                  .responseData[index]);
                        }),
                  );
                })
              ],
            ),
          ],
        )));
  }
}
```

this is my card file

```
// ignore_for_file: non_constant_identifier_names

       import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
  import 'package:flutter_html/flutter_html.dart';
        import 'package:get/get.dart';
  import 'package:newstv/colors.dart';
   import 'package:newstv/configs/config.dart';
    import 'package:newstv/controlller/news_controller.dart';
 import '../models/news_model.dart';
     import 'news_detailpage.dart';

   class CardWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  CardWidget({super.key, required this.model});
  final ResponseDatum? model;
  final NewsController newsController =
     Get.put(NewsController());

   @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
  width: double.infinity,
  margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: .0),
  child: Card(
    elevation: 4.0,
    child: ListTile(
      title: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
        children: [
          BackgroundImage(),
          Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              color: ThemeCode.textBackground,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    vertical: 5),
                child: Text(
                  model!.postTitle,
                  style:
                      TextStyle(color: ThemeCode.black),
                  maxLines: 1,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  softWrap: true,
                ),
              )),
        ],
      ),
      subtitle: Padding(
        padding:
            const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text('Date',
                style:
                    TextStyle(color: ThemeCode.black)),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 6,
            ),
            Html(
              data: model!.postDescription,
              style: {
                'p, div, span,h1, h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 ':
                    Style(color: ThemeCode.lightBlack)
              },
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 3,
            ),
            const Divider(
              color: Colors.black,
              thickness: 1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      onTap: () {
        Get.to(PostDetailPage(
          data: model,
        ));
         },
       ),
     ),
    );
 }

         BackgroundImage() {
    return Obx(
      () => newsController.isDataLoading.value
       ? const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        )
      : Container(
          width: Get.width * 1,
          height: 300,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
            image: NetworkImage(
                Config.imageURL + model!.postImage),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
             )),
           ),
         );
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the versions you are using:

- Flutter SDK v3.x
- flutter_html v2.x

I verified the problem you said by this version, please upgrade the flutter_html version to `v3.x`.

Although the version called `Pre-release`, it can solve this problem you said.

more: https://github.com/Sub6Resources/flutter_html/releases

Comment: This answer is useful

Comment: Can you please give me an example of how to use it? I'm struggling to embed HTML posts on my website

Comment: @genericUser Hi, could you paste the code that brings problem. I will try my best to solve it.